# While loop for incrementing file name value

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a function that organizes files in a directory based on extensions. For example, it makes a folder called `txt` and moves all text files into that folder. When there is already a txt folder and if there is a text file then it will automatically move it into that folder successfully. The problem is it won't move a file with the same name as the file in the txt directory.

[image]

This is the directory and inside the txt folder contains a file named `Text.txt` and the directory also contains a file named `Text.txt`, thus it's not able to move it into the folder, I tried using a while loop but I am not able to use it in the right place due to multiple for loops and complexity. Thanks!

```
def all_extensions_category(folder_to_track):
    if check_files(folder_to_track) == True:
        for file in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, file)) == False and os.listdir(folder_to_track).__len__() != 0:
                try:
                    file_mappings = collections.defaultdict()
                    for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)):
                            file_type = filename.split('.')[-1]
                            file_mappings.setdefault(file_type, []).append(filename)
        
                    for folder_name, folder_items in file_mappings.items():
                        folder_path = os.path.join(folder_to_track, folder_name)
                        folder_exists = os.path.exists(folder_path)
    
                        if not folder_exists:
                            os.mkdir(folder_path)
        
                        for folder_item in folder_items:
                            source = os.path.join(folder_to_track, folder_item)
                            destination = os.path.join(folder_path, folder_item)
                            os.rename(source, destination)
                    
                    return print("Successfully organized files based on extension")
                            
                except Exception as e:
                    return print(f'{folder_to_track}: is either empty or not organizable')
    
    else:
        return print(f'{folder_to_track}: is either empty or not organizable')
```

Comment: You should generally never compare a value to True or False. Simply use `if X:` or `if not Y:`. It's also unusual to see `return print("xyz")`. The `print` function doesn't return a value so you're not being clear and intentional here. I would `print` then `return` separately, as needed.

Comment: @jarmod will do that next time

Comment: Your question appears to be a very complex way of saying "I cannot rename file X to file Y if file Y already exists. What are my options?" to which the answer is "test if file Y already exists and, if so, delete it".

Comment: First of all, I don't want to delete file Y if it already exists, for example, if `Test.txt` already exists in the folder then I want to rename the file in the previous directory to `Test1.txt` when moved into the folder and next I am not sure how my question is very complex

Comment: I think if you re-read your original post, you'll see that it doesn't give any clue as to what behavior you actually want. It doesn't tell us if you want to rename a duplicate target, rename a duplicate source, delete a duplicate target, something else?

Comment: I am sorry if my question wasn’t clear,  I just wanted to know how you could rename a duplicate file using while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create files with increasing numbers like e.g. Windows does when copying a file with the same name, replace your `os.rename()` with following function:

```
def moveIncrementing(source, destination):
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            return os.rename(source, f"{destination}_{i}" if i else destination)
        except OSError as ex:
            i+=1
            print(ex)
```

It will keep trying to move the files until operation passes successfully. Just a warning, it will add numbers AFTER the file extension, so the files won't be properly recognized by their extension. But that's an excercise I'm leaving for you.

Comment: I think he wants to first try the destination name without a suffix, although that could be done in the caller first.

Comment: This function does that. If i is 0 else cause triggers and the destination is used as-is.

Comment: Oh, didn't see the `if`